# Date causing an error, not sure where to proceed

Tags: sql, vb.net

Every time I enter the date 2020, My program throws a Conversion error. It tells me that nvarchar to data type tiny int is wrong. 
My question is How would i go about fixing that? This is the part of the code where the error is being thrown.

```
           StrQuery = "UPDATE Schedule" &
           "SET JobEvents = JobEvents"  &
           " @JobEvents"  &
           "Where JobNumber = @JobNumber AND JobPhase = @JobPhase"

          SQLQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobEvents", StrEvent)
          SQLQuery.Parameters.AdddWithValue("@JobNumber", StrJobNumber)
          If StrJobPhase = "" Then
          SQLQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@JobPhase", 0)
          Else
          SQLQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobPhase", StrJobPhase)
          End If
          SQLQuery.CommandText = StrQuery
```

Comment: The easy way is to not use AddWithValue. Use any other way of adding the parameters, but not that. Just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: SQLQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@JobPhase", "0")

Comment: Also, you have a space missing beteen "Schedule" and "SET", and between " @JobEvents" and "Where". So maybe the AddWithEvents wasn't messing it up *this time*.

Comment: need to know what tghe data types are in teh db for JobEvents, JobNumber and JobPhase

Comment: Shoule i change the @JobPhase, 0 to another number?

Answer (score 2):

IF you would just print out your SQL statement, it'd be really easy to see what's wrong:

```
UPDATE ScheduleSET JobEvents = JobEvents @JobEventsWhere JobNumber = @JobNumber AND JobPhase = @JobPhase"
```

You have **no space** between the table name `Schedule` and the `SET` keyword, and also your assignment is totally broken - what is this??

```
SET JobEvents = JobEvents @JobEvents
```

and also, there's again **no space** between `@JobEvents` and the `where` keyword.....

You need to be a lot more careful when constructing those SQL statements from string concatenation!